# react-sortable-hoc stops after first move with edgeOffset

Tags: reactjs

I'm attempting to make a sortable table with react-sortable-hoc. This works fine for the first move but afterwards, react-sortable-hoc will stop working. The row in the table no longer animates and attempting to move an item throws the following error:

```
TypeError: edgeOffset is undefined
```

This is the relevant code:

```
const DragHandle = SortableHandle(() => <DragIndicatorIcon />);

const SortableItem = SortableElement(({ value, sortIndex, groupType }) => {
  return (
    <TableRow
      hover
      key={value.id}
      index={sortIndex}
    >
      <TableCell><DragHandle /></TableCell>
      <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
        {value.fullname}
      </TableCell>
      <TableCell numeric>{value.number}</TableCell>
      {groupType &&
        <TableCell>10</TableCell>
      }
    </TableRow>
  );
});

const SortableList = SortableContainer(({ items, groupType }) => {
  return (
    <TableBody>
      {items.map((user, index) => {
        return (
          <SortableItem key={`item-${index}`} groupType={groupType} index={index} sortIndex={index} value={user} />
        );
      })}
    </TableBody>
  );
});
```

And:

```
<Table className={classes.table}>
  <TableHead>
    <TableRow>
      <TableCell />
      <TableCell>Name</TableCell>
      <TableCell numeric>Number</TableCell>
      {this.props.groupType === "1" &&
        <TableCell>Seconds</TableCell>
      }
    </TableRow>
  </TableHead>
  <SortableList items={this.props.items} groupType={this.props.groupType === "1"} onSortEnd={this.props.onSortEnd} useDragHandle={true} useWindowAsScrollContainer={true} />
</Table>
```

Comment: since "edgeOffset" is not in your code, I presume this issue is very specific to react-sortable-hoc. It may be better to raise an issue in its github repo.